# Take screen shot from web view in android

Tags: android

I have a web view that I need to take a screenshot from a site. People suggested me use the function *capturePicture()*, this function is deprecated. So I create bitmap from current site like this and save it as byte[ ] to the database:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, stream);
DatabaseHelper.updateData(id, stream.toByteArray());
bitmap.recycle();
```

And load it in another Activity with **Glide**:

```
Glide.with(context).load(items.get(position).getImage())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_defualt)
            .into(holder.ivShot);
```

Now, If the number of screenshots increases, The speed of the app decreases and Memory size increases. I know that the issue of bitmaps is very complicated, But there must be a way to take a picture of the web view without any memory leaks or slowdowns.

I try to use threads to get bitmap but it doesn't help. Anyone know How I can do it?

Comment: try to take a screenshot in Asynctask and load it in the next activity.

Comment: @NensiKasundra It doesn't help too.

Comment: then create a screenshot file in internal storage and display from internal storage path

Comment: @NensiKasundra Part of my app is like a web browser. I want to make a tab screen. For example, Is google chrome save a preview of tabs in internal storage?

Comment: yes whatever is this you can save it in Internal Storage and in next activity you can show it

Comment: If you need then I will provide a code of store Bitmap in internal storage.

Comment: @NensiKasundra I thought it would be too slow, Isn't? Doesn't storing a photo in memory and then displaying it slows down it?

Comment: nope it's not slow down the performance

Comment: @NensiKasundra How to do this?

Comment: **1.** You already have a bitmap
**2.** from bitmap to you can create internal storage file in asynctask
**3.** pass that image path to the second Activity 
**4.** from path you can load an image in the second activity